# Is oracle DB able to return timezone region rather than just the offset?

Tags: oracle, timezone, timezone-offset

Is oracle DB able to return timezone region e.g. Europe/London rather than just the offset? I will like to know the region name where the server resides.

SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP param FROM DUAL; returns date, time and offset:

```
2020-08-17 18:11:03.219138 -05:00
```

SELECT DBTIMEZONE FROM dual; returns offset:

```
-05:00
```

Answer (score 3):

Oracle gets only timezone offset from OS, so it can't say what Region is set in OS, because there a lot of timezone regions with the same offset (-05:00).
But you can execute OS commands from within Oracle: `tzutil /g` on windows or `timedatectl` on Linux (or just read `/etc/timezone`) to get extended info.

**Update:** for example, you can use my package [xt_shell](https://github.com/xtender/xt_shell) to run OS commands with timeout and extended STDERR.

https://github.com/xtender/xt_shell

```sql
select * from table(xt_shell.shell_exec('/usr/bin/timedatectl',1000));
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from table(xt_shell.shell_exec('/usr/bin/timedatectl',1000));

COLUMN_VALUE
---------------------------------------------------
      Local time: Tue 2020-08-18 11:25:06 UTC
  Universal time: Tue 2020-08-18 11:25:06 UTC
        RTC time: Tue 2020-08-18 11:25:06
       Time zone: Europe/Berlin (UTC, +0000)
     NTP enabled: yes
NTP synchronized: yes
 RTC in local TZ: no
      DST active: n/a
```

Comment: @Theman please look at the updated answer. I've added an example with my package xt_shell